# UITextView's becomeFirstResponsder not working proprly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitextview

I have a `UIView` with a `UITextView` and `UITextField` as a subview. I want the keyboard to appear automatically on `textFieldShouldReturn` call.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    [textView becomeFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

but this does not work AND for some reason, it displays keyboard with cursor on next line in text view . I tried to set text nil in textview but it automatically call `textDidChange` method and cursor moves on new line without any text.

[image]

This same technique works correctly for a `UITextField` and also it works fine with iOS 5.0 but how to fix this in iOS 4.3. Let me know if you have any alternative as well.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Can you show more of the code? Also if your using a Storyboard I believe there is a way to have the UITextView be selected when the view first comes up, which should bring up the keyboard so you do not have to do it manually.

Comment: To add to Kinetic's comment, Storyboard projects only compile properly for iOS 5 so that could be an issue. If not, perhaps you're doing something funky in your UITextView delegate methods? Post more code for more specific help because the block you posted does not appear to be the problem.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There's a known bug in iOS with resigning and becoming first responder within the same runloop. Try the following

```
[textField resignFirstResponder];
[textView performSelector:@selector(becomeFirstResponder) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
```

Comment: By the way, I don't think you have to call resignFirstResponder before, I think becomeFirstResponder is enough.